# WxWidgets: wxQueueEvent Causing Segmentation Fault

Tags: c++, multithreading, wxwidgets

After a few days of battling this issue, I've decided to reach out for some help.

**Overview:** I am using std::thread to collect information from system peripherals. This information is going to be displayed on a wxFrame using events (values continuously updated, ~10ms). The issue at the stage of wxFrame handling events (I haven't gotten to the display-of-information portion of it yet). I've read through the event [documentation](https://docs.wxwidgets.org/3.0/overview_events.html) and I think my implementation is on the right path. I'm aware of threading samples with wxThread and wxThreadHelper, but my preference is to use std::thread and it seems like it should work.

**Issue:** The wxThreadEvent is generated in std::thread and sent using wxQueueEvent with the wxFrame as the target. The std::thread is started/managed in wxApp. The second event that is generated and queued by std::thread causes seg fault. Almost like the first event isn't being freed properly. Here some skimmed down set of code that I'm working with.

app.cpp:

```
wxIMPLEMENT_APP(ControlStationApp);

void communication_th(Comms * comms){
    int i = 0;
    while(i++ < 10){
        comms->test_thread();
        this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(3000));
    }
}

ControlStationApp::~ControlStationApp(){
    this->myThread.join();
}

bool ControlStationApp::OnInit(){
    
    if ( !wxApp::OnInit() ) return false;
    
    // Create the main frame window
    this->frame = new wxMainFrame;
    this->frame->Show(true);
    
    //Start peripheral thread
    Comms comms(this->frame);
    this->myThread = std::thread(communication_th, &comms);

    return true;
}
```

wxFrame.cpp

```
wxDEFINE_EVENT(wxEVT_COMMS_UPDATE, wxThreadEvent);

wxMainFrame::wxMainFrame() : wxFrame(NULL, wxID_ANY, "wxWidgets Layout Demo") {
    
    Bind(wxEVT_COMMS_UPDATE,&wxMainFrame::onCommsUpdate_t,this);
    
    ...
    
}

void wxMainFrame::onCommsUpdate_t(wxThreadEvent & e){
    std::cout << "threading eevnt!\n";
    e.Skip();
}

void wxMainFrame::OnClose(wxCloseEvent& evt){    
    Destroy();
}
```

std::thread .cpp

```
Comms::Comms(wxMainFrame * f){  
    this->mainFrame = f;
}

Comms::~Comms(){    
}

void Comms::test_thread(){
    std::cout << "Test_thread()\n";
    wxQueueEvent(this->mainFrame, new wxThreadEvent(wxEVT_COMMS_UPDATE);
}
```

This results in the following output:

```
Test_thread()
threading eevnt!
Test_thread()
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Any input is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: `this->myThread = std::thread(communication_th, &comms);` Ask yourself which lives longer: the thread you just created for `myThread`, or the `comms` object, whose address you're giving to that thread? The lifetime of `comms` literally ends on return of the very next line due to scope closure, thereby leaving the pointer just-passed to that thread now dangling. The comms object must live *at least* as long as the thread or this code is a recipe for undefined behavior.

Comment: @WhozCraig Ahhh! A beginner mistake. I keep doing that even in my day job. Good eye though! If you want to put this as an answer, I can accept it. Thanks for the help!